# How to implement an MDL data-selectable table inside a form

Tags: html, forms, checkbox, html-table, material-design

I have an MDL selectable table:

```
<form action="/counselors/{{ $counselor->id }}/badges/add" method="post">
  <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{ $badge->name }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<!-- submit button, etc -->
</form>
```

The table has checkboxes but in. However, the `mdl-data-table--selectable` class is what adds the checkboxes. How can i use these checkboxes as inputs for my form? there just needs to be a checkbox for each row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they deprecated the `mdl-data-table--selectable` class, in favor of adding the check boxes yourself ([source](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/wiki/Deprecations#user-content-automatic-selection-checkboxes))

This means that you should be able to link the check boxes up to a form now, sense you are the one responsible for making them.

I have modified the code you provided above according to the example provided on [this website](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/wiki/Deprecations#user-content-current-code).

```
<form action="/counselors/{{ $counselor->id }}/badges/add" method="post">
  <!-- vvv Remove 'mdl-js-data-table' and 'mdl-data-table--selectable' vvv -->
  <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <!-- vvv Manual Check Box Header vvv -->
        <th>
          <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-data-table__select" for="table-header">
            <input type="checkbox" id="table-header" class="mdl-checkbox__input" />
          </label>
        </th>
        <!-- ^^^ Manual Check Box Header ^^^ -->

        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>

        <!-- vvv Manual Check Box Row vvv -->
        <td>
          <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-data-table__select" for="row[1]">
            <input type="checkbox" id="row[1]" class="mdl-checkbox__input" />
          </label>
        </td>
        <!-- ^^^ Manual Check Box Row ^^^ -->

        <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{ $badge->name }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<!-- submit button, etc -->
</form>
```